# How do I get inputs and raise events for the outside world in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to know how can one get inputs from the outside world and raise custom events that bubbles up to the outside world (i.e. outside of angular components). I understand I cannot get `@Input()` in the root component. Then how can I do the following:

1. Pass an array of object (say `T[]`) to my Angular components `<app-root>` from outside of angular.
2. raise an event from `<app-grandchild>` such that the event bubbles out of angular components and hits the DOM tree root or `<body>`.

Assume the following DOM hierarchy:

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <app-child>
      <app-grandchild></app-grandchild>
    </app-child>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: [Use the `@HostListener` decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

Comment: Thanks for you response, what if I want this event to be handled outside of angular? How would I get access to the ``$event` object?

Comment: You should provide 2 concrete examples as you have 2 questions. 1. Provide a concrete example of the data provider of this array of `T[]`. Where is coming from? Another .js library? An API? How are you interfacing with this API or library? 2) What is subscribing to your application? An API, something that listens to a windows event? Be more specific.

Comment: You use custom events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Thanks @cgTag that was helpful. I knew about this but I just wanted to see if there was an angular way of bubbling events outside angular components. But, I guess not.

Comment: If you're looking for the Angular way, then you should read up on Angular Elements which fellows the web component standards. https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 1):

Your question requires an explanation of a couple of concepts from Angular: Component Interaction and content projection.

I've put together an example that combines both to meet what you described in your question:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let obj of arrayOfObjects"> {{ obj.id }} </li>
  </ul>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
class AppChildComponent {
    @Input() arrayOfObjects: object[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grandchild',
  template: `Am the grandchild!`,
})
class AppGrandChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() somethingHappened = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.somethingHappened.emit('yellow');
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-child [arrayOfObjects]="[
      {id: '123'},
      {id: '456'}
    ]">
        <app-grandchild 
          (somethingHappened)="handleSomething($event)">
        </app-grandchild>
    </app-child>
  `,
})
class AppComponent {
    handleSomething(event){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = event;
  }
}
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/c945j08v/1/

I strongly recommend you reading more on Angular Docs & Blog.

- https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
- https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

I hope this helps.